# Optimizar código en Google Apps Script - GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una macro en una hoja de calculo en **Google Apps Script** y aunque funciona bien su rendimiento no es el mejor, es lenta.... ¿Creen que puedo mejorarlo?

```
function Busqueda() {

  var valorBuscar = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIN').getRange('F2').getValue();
  var FilaEscribir = 9;

  if (valorBuscar == ""){
      Browser.msgBox('Debes ingresar una identificación valida');
      }
  else if (valorBuscar != ""){

      // Se consulta el total de hojas
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
      var string;

      for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
             string = sheets[i].getName();

             for (var c=1 ; c<2000 ; c++) {
                 //Browser.msgBox('Registro: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(string).getRange('A'+ c).getValue() + ' VS ' + valorBuscar);
                 if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(string).getRange('A'+ c).getValue() == valorBuscar) {
                    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIN').getRange('B' + FilaEscribir).setValue(string);
                    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIN').getRange('C' + FilaEscribir).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(string).getRange('A'+ c).getValue());
                    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIN').getRange('D' + FilaEscribir).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(string).getRange('B'+ c).getValue());
                    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIN').getRange('E' + FilaEscribir).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(string).getRange('C'+ c).getValue());
                     FilaEscribir = FilaEscribir +1;
                  }  // END if         

             } // END for c

        } // END for i

    } // END de limpieza
}; // END function
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Google desaconseja el uso de `Browser.msgBox(mensaje)`. En su lugar usa `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message)`.
2. Evita hacer llamadas a los servicios de Google en bucles (for loops y demás). En este caso en particular, lee los datos usando una llamada al servicio de SpreadsheetApp y otra para pasar datos a la hoja.

Answer (score 0):

Hace bastante que se hizo esta pregunta, pero creo que mi respuesta es válida.

Donde se te va todo tiempo es en el setValue dentro de un bucle

Haces 2000 iteraciones por hoja que tengas en el spreadsheet.

Dentro de cada iteración haces 8 getRange de celdas individuales. Esto da 16000 interacciones con celdas por cada hoja. Es una auténtica animalada.

1.Usa getValues() de la hoja MAIN y guarda el array en una variable.

2.Para cada hoja que inspecciones, haz un getValues() y guarda el array en una variable.

3.Cuando hagas los if, no uses el getRange(...).getValue() sino que directamente ves a mirarlo al array que tienes guardado array[x][y]. (Esto es virtualmente instantaneo por que no ataca a la hoja para obtener el valor)

4.No hagas setValue de lo que necesites sino que deberias guardar la información a escribir en un array ( el mismo que has creado al principio te servirá para ir modificando los valores )

5. Cuando acabes de procesar la hoja ( o cuando acabes el script ) puedes hacer un setValues(array). De esta forma solo hará un acceso a la hoja para imprimir los datos.

Si haces lo que te digo te debería ir el script bastante más rápido ( un par de ordenes de magnitud ).

Si tienes dudas, puedes mirarte estos links: Como optimizar la [escritura](https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2016/04/como-optimizar-la-escritura-en.html) && Como optimizar la [lectura](https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2016/05/como-optimizar-la-lectura-de.html)