# Optimizar script o aumentar tiempo de ejecucion en una hoja de calculo de google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, optimización

esta seria la segunda parte de un post que realice hace poco: [Script recorrido de filas y columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/260105/script-recorrido-de-filas-y-columnas/260150#260150)

En esta parte le he añadido un array, para que me recorra ciertas hojas y posterior mente hacer un loop sobre estas y ejecutar el codigo anterior.

```
function myFunction() {

  var hojas = [

    "Calvià",
    "Inca",
    "Manacor",
    "LLucmajor",
    "Sóller",
    "Artà",
    "Alcudia",
    "Felaitx"

  ]

  var nombres = 2;
  var parque = 2;
  var posiciong = 2;
  var posiciongr = 2;

  for (i=0; i<hojas.length + 1; i++){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(hojas[i]);
    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();

    for (r=7; r<lastrow+1; r++){

        var G = 0;
        var GR = 0;
        var range = ss.getRange(r,1).getValue();

        if (range!=0){

          var range2 = ss.getRange(r,4).getValue();
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(nombres, 1).setValue(range);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(parque, 2).setValue(range2);
          nombres = nombres + 1;
          parque = parque +1;

          for (c=6; c<93; c++){

            var rangec = ss.getRange(r,c).getValue().toString();

            if (rangec=="G"){

              G = G + 1;

            }if (rangec=="GR"){

              GR = GR + 1;

            }

          }

          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(posiciong, 3).setValue(G);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(posiciongr, 4).setValue(GR);
          posiciong = posiciong + 1;
          posiciongr = posiciongr + 1;

        }

    }

  }

}
```

Creo que el codigo esta bien, pero el problema es que tarda mas de 5 minutos en ejecutarse completamente y me da tiempo de ejecución finalizado. La pregunta es si seria posible optimizar el script para que tardara menos o aumentar el tiempo de ejecución, esta segunda opción he leido que no se puede hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los servicios de Google Apps Script como SpreadsheetApp son "caros" en términos de tiempo de ejecución por eso se aconseja siempre que sea posible usar los métodos que devuelven matrices como `setValues` en lugar de los que devuelven valores puntuales como `setValue`.

En concreto, considera en lugar de usar `setValue` en tu sentencia `for` usar un Array 2D y pasar todos los valores con un sólo `setValues` luego dicha sentencia.

Otro cosa que podría ayudar es que en lugar de llamar `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras")` cada vez que llames `getRange` asigna este a una variable.

Mi práctica es minimizar el uso de cadenas, en cierta medida porque esto ayuda a la depuración del código cuando esto sea necesario y porque tener sentencias cortas facilita la lectura del código. Creo que además esto ayuda a la optimización de ejecución que realiza Google Apps Script internamente pero no he hecho pruebas.

En cuanto a aumentar el tiempo límite, las cuentas de G Suite tienen un límite de 30 minutos.

Relacionado

- [Optimizar código en Google Apps Script - GAS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/249749/65)
- [Cómo optimizar un script para ocultar filas en Hoja de Cálculo de Google, según criterios variables de una columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/201689/65)

Comment: "En concreto, considera en lugar de usar setValue en tu sentencia for usar un Array 2D y pasar todos los valores con un sólo setValues luego dicha sentencia." Puedo hacer que cada bloque del array contenga 4 valores? La unica forma que se me ocurre utilizando arrays es creando 4 distintas y recorrerlas con el for al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @IvánMontero `setValues` requiere un Array cuyos miembros sean de tipo Array cada uno representando una fila, donde el primer elemento corresponde a la celda de intersección con la primer columna, el segundo con la segunda celda de intersección con la segunda columna y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, lo que me estas diciendo es que cree un array que contenga todas las filas, donde cada posicion del array es una fila de la hoja y luego utilizar el `setvalues` filtrando lo que quiero que me obtenga?

Comment: Tu array, debe tener un array por cada fila. Quizás te resulte útil usar getValues con un rango con datos conocidos para que tengas más claro de que hablo.

Comment: Entonces lo que dices es que cree un array que contenga otro array dentro? Siento el tiempo que tardo en responder, me lian con otras cosas xd.

Comment: No sólo uno, muchos arrays, uno por cada fila de datos.

Comment: Esta opcion aumentaria el tiempo de ejecucion a mi parecer, puesto que tiene que procesar mas.

Comment: Lo que determina el tiempo de ejecución no se limita a lo que se tiene que procesar también afecta quien lo va  a procesar, entre otras cosas. Cómo te decía previamente los métodos de SpreadsheetApp son lentos, muy lentos.