# Cómo mejorar la velocidad de una función en Google Apps Script que trabaja con muchos registros

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, rendimiento, eficiencia

Tengo una tabla con miles de registros (ahora más de 6000) y he creado una función que comprueba aquellas filas que tienen un valor concreto en una de sus celdas (empieza por PARA, por ejemplo "PARA C1") y copia la fila a otra hoja de cálculo, cambiando el valor "PARA C1" por "C1").
Inicialmente iba muy rápido pero a medida que iba metiendo más filas, se iba ralentizando y ahora, cada operación tarda alrededor de 20 segundos. Si tengo que aplicar la función sobre varias filas (al principio iba bien con más de 100 pero ahora solo hace 30 como máximo), llega a exceder el límite de tiempo.
Para reducir el tiempo, hice los siguientes cambios:

- En lugar de consultar toda la tabla, consultaba solamente la columna en la que compruebo el dato.
- Luego introduje en un array los índices de las celdas que se esperan pasar para recorrer únicamente esos valores.
- Por último, hice que en lugar de empezar desde la segunda fila, el usuario introdujera desde qué posición se espera comenzar.
  El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente (comento para aclarar):

```
    /*Esta función recorre todas las filas de la hoja "General". Aquellas en las que ponga "PARA C1", "PARA C2"...
    se pasan los datos al final de la hoja "GENERAL" de la hoja de cáálculo "COMERCIALES" y se cambia el estado a "C1", "C2"...*/
    function copiarDatosGeneralAcomerciales() {
      if (mostrarMensajeCopiarDatosGeneralAComerciales()){ //El usuario debe aceptar el proceso
      //Es un prompt que pide al usuario desde qué celda comienza a buscar datos
      var numeroInicioCeldas = mostrarMensajeNumeroInicioCeldas();

      if (numeroInicioCeldas) {
      var hojaCalculoActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var hojaCalculoId = hojaCalculoActiva.getId();

      var hojaCalculoComercialesId = "***********************";

      var hojaGeneral = "GENERAL";

      var hojaCalculoGeneral = SpreadsheetApp.openById(hojaCalculoId).getSheetByName(hojaGeneral);
      var hojaCalculoComerciales = SpreadsheetApp.openById(hojaCalculoComercialesId).getSheetByName(hojaGeneral);

      //NUMEROS DE COLUMNAS 
      var cCodigo = getNumColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "CODIGO");
      var cNombre = getNumColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "NOMBRE");
      var cTelefono = getNumColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "TELEFONO");
      var cCampana = getNumColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "CAMPAÑA");
      var cComercial = getNumColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "COMERCIAL");

      //Tomamos los datos de la hoja desde la fila introducida por el usuario hasta la última que tiene datos (es decir, un número en la primera celda)
      // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) 
    var datos = hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(numeroInicioCeldas, cComercial+1, getUltimaFilaConDatosDeUnaColumna(hojaCalculoId, hojaGeneral, "A"), 1).getValues();

      var filasConPara = []; //Array que almacena POSICIONES de filas que contienen datos desde el número de inicio introducido
      var contadorFila=numeroInicioCeldas; //Empieza por la fila introducida por el usuario
      var row, r;
      datos.forEach(function (r){
        if (r[0].substring(0, 4)=="PARA"){ //Comprueba las filas que comienzan por la palabra "PARA"
          filasConPara.push(contadorFila);
        }
        contadorFila++
      });

      for (var i=0; i<filasConPara.length; i++){
          r = hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i],1,1,hojaCalculoGeneral.getLastColumn()).getValues();
          nombreComercial = r[0][cComercial].substr(r[0][cComercial].length - 2); 
          row =  [r[0][cCodigo], r[0][cNombre], r[0][cTelefono], r[0][cCampana], nombreComercial];
          hojaCalculoComerciales.appendRow(row);
          
          //var celdaCXParaCambiar = hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i], cComercial+1); (1)
          //celdaCXParaCambiar.setValue(nombreComercial); (2)
          //Paso las instrucciones 1 y 2 en una sola
          hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i], cComercial+1).setValue(nombreComercial);

        }
      }
    }
}
```

¿Podríais darme alguna idea para mejorar la velocidad de la función?

Comment: El código no está completo, falta la declaración de `getNumColumna`

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos de los servicios de Google Apps Script son "muy lentos". En [el artículo oficial sobre mejores prácticas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) se recomienda evitar uso en bucles.

Considerando lo anterior, al menos deberías modificar la siguiente parte del código en la pregunta para mejor su desempeño:

```javascript
      for (var i=0; i<filasConPara.length; i++){
          r = hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i],1,1,hojaCalculoGeneral.getLastColumn()).getValues();
          nombreComercial = r[0][cComercial].substr(r[0][cComercial].length - 2); 
          row =  [r[0][cCodigo], r[0][cNombre], r[0][cTelefono], r[0][cCampana], nombreComercial];
          hojaCalculoComerciales.appendRow(row);
          
          //var celdaCXParaCambiar = hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i], cComercial+1); (1)
          //celdaCXParaCambiar.setValue(nombreComercial); (2)
          //Paso las instrucciones 1 y 2 en una sola
          hojaCalculoGeneral.getRange(filasConPara[i], cComercial+1).setValue(nombreComercial);

        }
```

1. En lugar de leer una fila en cada iteración, lee los datos antes del bucle
2. En lugar de agregar una fila en cada iteración con `appendRow`, crea un Array al que agregues los valores de todas las filas. Luego después del bucle escribe todas las filas a la vez.

Relacionado

- [Cómo optimizar un script para ocultar filas en Hoja de Cálculo de Google, según criterios variables de una columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/201689/65)
- [Optimizar código en Google Apps Script - GAS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/249749/65)
- [Optimizar script o aumentar tiempo de ejecucion en una hoja de calculo de google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/260432/65)